# Json.Net Deserialize dictionary without property name

Tags: c#, json, .net, .net-core, json.net

I already looked at a lot of other questions with the same problem but never found a definitive solution that actually works for me. I tried using the JsonExtensionData Attribute, that doesn't work though since I can't convert my other data class to an object and it throws the `Invalid extension data attribute on 'NAMESPACE'. Member 'Sols' type must implement IDictionary<string, JToken>.` error.

My current data model class looks like this

```
public partial class Mars
{
    public Dictionary<string, Sol> Sols { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("sol_keys")]
    public List<long> SolKeys { get; set; }
}

public partial class Sol
{
    [JsonProperty("AT")]
    public At At { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("First_UTC")]
    public DateTimeOffset FirstUtc { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Last_UTC")]
    public DateTimeOffset LastUtc { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Season")]
    public string Season { get; set; }
}

public partial class At
{
    [JsonProperty("av")]
    public double Av { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("ct")]
    public long Ct { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("mn")]
    public double Mn { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("mx")]
    public double Mx { get; set; }
}
```

The json data looks like this

```
{
    "651": 
    {
        "AT": 
        {
            "av": -61.957,
            "ct": 302204,
            "mn": -96.733,
            "mx": -15.877
        },
        "First_UTC": "2020-09-25T02:42:14Z",
        "Last_UTC": "2020-09-26T03:21:49Z",
        "Season": "summer"
    },
    "652": {
        "AT": {
            "av": -65.002,
            "ct": 278608,
            "mn": -96.111,
            "mx": -15.653
        },
        "First_UTC": "2020-09-26T03:21:50Z",
        "Last_UTC": "2020-09-27T04:01:24Z",
        "Season": "summer"
    },
    "sol_keys": [
        "646",
        "647",
        "648",
        "649",
        "650",
        "651",
        "652"
    ]
}
```

I can't really modify the json data since I get it from an api.
I basically just want to select one of the numbers and then get the Sol data of that object.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSON doesn't fit well with the C# type system. However, you can still use Json.Net to parse it. You just need to introduce some extra steps.

First step is to parse the JSON to a `JObject`:

```
var jObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(json);
```

Then you can extract the `sol_keys`:

```
var solKeys = jObject.GetValue("sol_keys").ToObject<long[]>();
```

Now it becomes a bit tricky. If you remove the `sol_keys` from the JSON (in this case the parsed JSON) it has the structure of a dictionary of `Sol` objects that you are able to parse:

```
jObject.Remove("sol_keys");
var mars = jObject.ToObject<Dictionary<long, Sol>>();
```

Now you have both `solKeys` and `mars` parsed from the JSON. Furthermore the `solKeys` and the keys in the dictionary share the same type (`long`).

Comment: Exactly what I asked for. And yeah, the json provided by the api is pretty weird. If you're wondering its from the official Nasa api